# SP 2013: The item has been truncated in the index because it exceeds the maximum size

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

Our crawler shows the following warning:

> *The item has been truncated in the index because it exceeds the maximum size. ( Item truncated. Field=docacl, Occurrences=3094,
>   Chars=524453.*

It concerns a SharePoint 2013 site-collection in 2010 mode. It refers to list items with unique permissions. Maximum of 10 groups per item. 400 items in the list itself.

When you google for this issue you will often find the following link:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/the-item-has-been-truncated-in-the-index-because-it-exceeds-the-maximum-size/

However, changing that property doesn't actually do anything unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a multi value property then the max limit is 1000 instances.

As per [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Search) a managed property can only store 1000 unique values per item. Your message says over 3000.

If it's a single value you can increase the MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex property using the following powershell script:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity "docacl"
$mp.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex = 2097152
$mp.Update()
```

Comment: Didn't even think that the occurrences would be an issue...That would mean search would not work on any item that gives access to more than 1000 users? Doesn't seem to be that strange of a use case.

Comment: To be sure, when you increase the limit from 512kb to 2mb, do you see an increase in the Chars= error when indexing? As you should see this.

Comment: @MartijnBijl Hmm.. as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630%28v=office.15%29.aspx docacl is not multivalue, so the storage limit should apply, and my answer might be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the warning remains the exact same. We changed the property, did an IISReset and restarted the search service.

Comment: Trying to reproduce it, but hard to dummy create enough users to fill the docacl field. In theory it should be possible to change the the size. Are you doing it on the SSA level?

Comment: This is the powershell we are using: $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity "docacl"
$mp.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreForRetrieval = 2097152
$mp.Update()

Comment: You should set MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.managedproperty.maxcharactersinpropertystoreindex(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I'll try that the upcoming Monday. I feel pretty stupid if it is that easy. On the other hand, its hard to look for stuff when you don't know what to look for :)

Comment: The warnings have gone away :) Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect both multival and singleval properties.

Comment: And the story continues....no more warnings but certain users do still not get the expected results. Sometimes they do, when the ACL list is short. So its not a problem at list / permission level. Any suggestions as to where to pay attention too? Going to search through the SharePoint logs in a bit if we can find anything

Comment: Can you say something about how many unique permissions you have for a failing item? And maybe you need to set both params...which is weird.

Comment: The other parameter is at the same amount, so 2097152. Failing items usually have about 10 SP groups consisting out of a total of approximately 6000 users.

Comment: That would be a bitch to reproduce in a test environment ;)

Comment: Tell me about it :P

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the logs that meant anything significant to me. Compared the logs for a query that I did versus one of the users that had an issue. Looks completely the same except that the user gets 0 relevant results and I get 10. But the user is able to go navigate to those 10 items directly :x

Comment: Can you try to do a full crawl after the change? Or have you already?

Comment: Well the problem has gone away. So maybe the last issue was a caching issue somewhere. :) thanks for all your help!